# How to use PostGIS for tile-based aggregation?

Tags: postgis, aggregation, spatial-analysis

How can I create a tile-based aggregation of polygons with PostgreSQL/PostGIS?
The input of such an operation could be the database table with the geometry and the data to aggregate, a bounding box, and the tile size and the method which should be used for the aggregation (sum, average, minimum, maximum).

The output would be a list of geometries with the outlines of the tiles and the aggregated values.

I found this operation in Oracle Spatial but could not find a solution on how to do this with PostGIS.

Comment: The function of Oracle SDO_SAM.TILED_AGGREGATES (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_sam_ref.htm#SPATL1205) which is doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [ST_Union](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ST_Union.html) function would do it... how were you doing this with Oracle?

Comment: Can ST_UNION be used to aggregate values?